# How to extends types for section element in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In typescript, when our component extends a `div` we define our props types like this:

```
import { HTMLAttributes } from "react";

export interface IContainerProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
    // You can add additional props specific to your container component here
    customProp?: string;
  }
```

However, when the component props extends section element props, I did not find something like this `HTMLSectionElement`:

In typescript, when our component extends a `div` we define our props types like this:

```
import { HTMLAttributes } from "react";

// HTMLSectionElement does not exist ?

export interface IContainerProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLSectionElement> {
    // other props
  }
```

Comment: There is no HTMLSectionElement for a good reason: it is exactly the same as a HTMLElement. Said differently, it does not come with properties of methods that HTMLElement doesn't come with. You can safely use HTMLElement...or create a type alias if you prefer using the HTMLSectionElement type.

Comment: Also [MDN on section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) mentions *This element only includes the global attributes.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the `IntrinsicElements` in `node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts`, to inspect how React types this:

```js
interface IntrinsicElements {
  // ...
  div: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>;
  // ...
  section: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>;
  // ...
}
```

So the type you are looking for is `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>`. This type is consistent with the fact that `section` is primarily used as a semantic tag and [contains no unique attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section#attributes).

> This element only includes the [global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes).